# SweetAlert2: Really no way to stop JS code until a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, sweetalert2

In the Swal Github is advised to ask questions to SweetAlert2 in SO, therefore my posting here...

Behind a save button in my (asp.net core) app, I check some things and - in some cases - have to ask the user (yes/no) and - depending on his selection - have to **overwrite** some data **before** store.

If I use an (jQuery) alert or a confirm, the code stops, until the user has clicked a button.
In Swal, I don’t have found any way (including “.then(“) to **stop** the code, until the user has clicked a button.
The message is shown, but the code runs further....

Is it really **not** possible to stop the code with Swal...?
**=> If there is a way, how to do...?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, as there is really **now way** to **stop** the JS code until the user has done his chosen
So.. I had to change my logic.
**Logic before:**

[image: Logic before]

To check something **( 1 )** , show an swal (e.g. set focus to a control) and then return in code works (of cause of the return).
This way,the message is showed (until the user close it) and the data are not stored.
To ask the user something in a swal (Do you really want to..." and then do some things based in the answer of the user **before** the date are stored, **don't work**, as the JS Code ist **not** stopped until the user has made a choice.
Der swal is showed, but the data data are saved **( 3 )** immediately (no wait here).

To reach what I need, I had to change the logic.
**New Logic**

[image: New Logic]
I had to **decouple** the check logic from the save:
No change to the check **( 1 )**
Move the save of the data **( 3 )** in a separated function (SaveData())
Give out the swal **( 2 )** and then call SaveData() **( 3 )** from the swal functions.

My code to the swal:

```
  if ((AvatarHochgeladen) && (!(AvatarUebernommen))) {
  swal.fire({
    title: '! Achtung !',
    html: 'Sie haben eine eigene Grafik hochgeladen, diese aber nicht mit dem Button "Ihren upload übernehmen" als aktuellen Avatar übernommen. <br> Wenn Sie die Daten so speichern, geht Ihr hochgeladener Avatar verloren. <br> Wollen Sie Ihre hochgeladene Grafik als Avatar speichern?',
    icon: 'question',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: 'blue',
    cancelButtonText: 'Nein',
    confirmButtonText: 'Ja',
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      AvatarSpeichern = AvatarBase64;
      SaveUserdata();
    }
    else { SaveUserdata(); }
  })
  }
```

So.. if the user chose "Yes", I replace a variable and call SaveData(), if the user chose "No" I directly call SaveData().
**My conclusion:**
As swal is "non blocking" (don't stop a running JS script), we have to split the logic and call (from the user choice depending) code from swal internal.

Answer (score 0):

It supports callback right? Here is some code which I found in the [examples](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples).

```
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
allowOutsideClick: false,
allowEscapeKey: false,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        Swal.fire(
          'Deleted!',
          'Your file has been deleted.',
          'success'
        )
      }
    })
```

You can continue the execution based on the result.value

Comment: Thanks for your posting, but this DON'T stop the JS code (I have tried this (and other example code I found) already). I think, it's not possible and I have to add a further function (split the code) before data save.

Answer (score 0):

I Try:

```
function delete_rec_sub_button(id) {

    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {

        if (result.isConfirmed) {

            delete_rec_sub_button.yesKill();
        }
    });

    delete_rec_sub_button.yesKill = function() {

        //real code delete(id)

        if('return sucess of delete'){
            
            Swal.fire(
            'Deleted!',
            'Your file has been deleted.',
            'success'
            )

        }else{

            Swal.fire(
            'error!',
            'Unable to delete, current record is in use',
            'error'
            )

        }

    };
}
```